# Change color of bootstrap navbar on hover link?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, colors, navbar

I want to know how to change the color of the links when you hover over them in the nav bar, as currently they are an ugly color.

Thanks for any suggestions?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link One</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Two</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link Three</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in future please post your HTML (and any other code) *into the question itself*, that way it's legible to viewers.

Answer (score 95):

For *Bootstrap 3* this is how I did this based on the default [Navbar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) structure:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #FFFF00;
    color: #FFC0CB;
}
```

Comment: upvote because the specificity keeps from having to use !important. Not that !important can't be used sometimes but I like this better.

Comment: For me it worked with navbar instead of navbar-default. Obviously depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 55):

This is cleaner:

```
ul.nav a:hover { color: #fff !important; }
```

There's no need to get more specific than this. Unfortunately, the `!important` is necessary in this instance.

I also added `:focus` and `:active` to the same declaration for accessibility reasons and for smartphone/tablet/touchscreen users.

Comment: Try using this is a complex site and not ruin your site. You need to use class names. If you have another <ul> with a <nav> inside with an <a> tag inside that it, this style will effect it as well.

Answer (score 18):

You can try this to change the link background on hover

```
.nav > li > a:hover{
    background-color:#FCC;
}
```

Comment: Please add some description to your answer.

Comment: Thank you  -Worked - but using bootstrap 4

Answer (score 17):

***Updated 2018***

You can change the **Navbar link colors** with CSS to override Bootstrap colors...

**Bootstrap 4**

```
.navbar-nav .nav-item .nav-link {
    color: red;
}
.navbar-nav .nav-item.active .nav-link,
.navbar-nav .nav-item:hover .nav-link {
    color: pink;
}
```

[Bootstrap 4 navbar link color demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/Za19bSdEKg)

**Bootstrap 3**

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a,
.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a{
    color: orange;
}

.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: red;
}
```

[Bootstrap 3 navbar link color demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/Z9odX8CmCC)

---

The change or **customize the entire Navbar color**, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18530995/171456

Answer (score 9):

You would have to overwrite the CSS rule:

```
.navbar-inverse .brand, .navbar-inverse .nav > li > a
```

or

```
.navbar .brand, .navbar .nav > li > a
```

depending if you are using the dark or light theme, respectively. To do this, add a CSS with your overwritten rules and make sure it comes in your HTML **after** the Bootstrap CSS. For example:

```
.navbar .brand, .navbar .nav > li > a {
    color: #D64848;
}
.navbar .brand, .navbar .nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #F56E6E;
}
```

There is also the alternative where you customize your own Boostrap [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/customize.html). In this case, in the **Navbar** section, you have the `@navbarLinkColor`.

Comment: hmm when i search for those two statements, it comes back saying they cant be found? Shall i post the css for bootstrap?

Comment: In my case I just wanted a specific background color on hover, so I did this, on bootstrap 5.3: .navbar-nav li:hover>a {
  background-color: var(--bs-primary-bg-subtle);
}

Answer (score 4):

Target the element you wish to change and use `!important` to overwrite any existing styles that are assigned to that element. Be sure not to use the `!important` declaration when it is not absolutely necessary.

```
div.navbar div.navbar-inner ul.nav a:hover {
    color: #fff !important; 
}
```

Comment: I just cant find any hover statement which affects the navbars hover. It seems like the .navbar-link:hover, statement, would do it but it does not

Comment: if you copy and paste my code into your css it will take over the nav bar current attribute and apply this one for hover.

Answer (score 4):

Use Come thing link this , This is Based on Bootstrap 3.0

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    background-color: #977EBD;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    background-color: #977EBD;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
.nav > li > a:focus, 
.nav > li > a:hover 
{
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sorry for late reply. You can only use:

```
   nav a:hover{

                   background-color:color name !important;


                 }
```

Comment: Hey Farhan, it seems this is exactly the same solution that was added by trebor1979 at answered Sep 27 '13 or am I missing some detail here? :)

P.S. sorry for the comment spam in your inbox. The stackoverflow UI was fooling me into submitting my comment early.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this has worked for me (with Bootstrap 3):

```
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus{
    font-family: proxima-nova;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
}
```

In my case I also wanted the link text to remain black before the hover so i added **.navbar-nav > li > a**

```
.navbar-nav > li > a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-nav > li > a{
    font-family: proxima-nova;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a{
  color: #e9b846;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover{
  background-color: #e9b846;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: is it different from other answers?

Answer (score 0):

If you **Navbar** code as like as follow:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

Then just use the following CSS style to change hover color of your **navbar-brand**

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus {
     color: white;
}
```

So your `navbad-brand` hover color will be changed to white. I just tested it and it's working for me correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough:

```
.nav.navbar-nav li a:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped me!

```
.navbar-light .navbar-nav > li > a:hover,
.navbar-light .navbar-nav > li > a:focus {
    color:  black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some time, that's what worked for me. Changing only css.

```
.navbar-inner .navbar-brand:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Bootstrap 5 you can simply use:

```
.nav-link:hover{
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With bootstrap 5 the best if you familiar with scss recompile.

Add in the **_nav.scss** this for a dark gray for example then rebuild the css files:

```
.nav-item {
  &:hover, &:focus {
      background-color: $gray-800;
    }
}
```