# Override Bootstrap hover on navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'd like to override the font color when I hover over a tab/link on my navbar. I currently have the following HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class = "container">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

            </ul>
            <ul class ="nav pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                <li ><a href="#">Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just would like the tabs on the right to turn a different color. I understand pseudoselectors, I'm just wondering how I'd properly do this with my own CSS. Thanks!

Comment: .nav a:hover { color: red !important;} or .nav li:hover > a { color: red !important;} ? not sure

Comment: its duplicate though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625972/change-color-of-bootstrap-navbar-on-hover-link?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the selector is specific enough, you can avoid usage of `!important`. In this case, you would use:

```
.nav.pull-right > li > a:hover {
    /* style .. */
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/EUt4u/)

Alternatively, you could also use `.navbar-inner .container .nav.pull-right > li > a:hover`

Comment: Works like a charm. I was missing the extra "." for the pull-right section when I was adding my CSS (so I had .nav pull-right instead). Thanks!