# Change hover-over font color of navbarPage menu bar in R Shiny

Tags: css, r, fonts, shiny, navbar

I'm attempting to change the colour of the font when the mouse hovers over the options on the navbarPage menubar in an R Shiny app by using a CSS file with contents:

```
.navbar-default:hover {
    color: #F2E836;
    background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

However, this isn't working for me. Any guesses as to why?

Comment: can you please share your html markup?

Comment: Hi. I'm quite new to all of this; what do you mean by your question? All I have is an R Shiny app using the navbarPage feature, and a separate CSS file with the contents above. I've been able to successful change the formatting of other parts of the menubar with the same CSS file, such as the background colour, so not sure why the above isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
    color: #F2E836 !important;
    background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Omit `!important` if the style applies without it.

`!important` overrides other styles already defined on the same element. It is not a good practice to overuse `!important` as it makes obscure which line of CSS is applied to which element.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Could you elaborate further on what the `!important` bit means?

Comment: Thanks for explaining further.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Change color of bootstrap navbar on hover link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16625972/change-color-of-bootstrap-navbar-on-hover-link)

(Apologies for repeating the question, but my question's title certainly more accurately reflects what I wanted to find out, hence why my searching didn't readily reveal the existing question!)